# inverse limits - Differentiability

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives

suppose that $u$ is differentiable function and verifies:
$$\lim_{x\to +\infty}u(x)=1$$
do we have $\lim_{x\to +\infty}u'(x)=0$?

My idea: we inserve limits

$$\lim_{x\to +\infty}u'(x)=lim_{x\to +\infty}\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{u(x+h)-u(x)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}lim_{x\to +\infty}\frac{u(x+h)-u(x)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{1-1}{h}=0$$

Comment: @mvpq yes! thank s for the remark

Comment: Why can you switch the limit operators here?

Comment: Why do you believe the limit of $u'$ exists.  Consider (vertical translations of) $u(x) = \sin(x^2)/x$.

Comment: @EricTowers I supposed that $u$ is differentible. but I think this only works when $u'$ is continuous

Comment: $f(x) = \sin(x)$ is continuous (everywhere) and differentiable (everywhere) but neither $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x)$ nor $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f'(x)$ exist.

Comment: @HansLundmark yes! Thank you for the suggestion